# Jmeter game testing

Tags: performance

please someone help me to understand jmeter testing and help me on my project. Most of the apis got failed

{"success":false,"status_code":500,"message":"Internal server error","err":{"description":"Something went wrong","error":{"expose":true,"statusCode":400,"status":400,"body":"{\r\n\t"phone_no" : "14${counter}0001000",\r\n\t"country_code" : "+91",\r\n}","type":"entity.parse.failed"}},"time":1700330444611}

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible that the error message that is returned to you in this case constitutes a valid result for your JMeter test.  That is, your test elicited server errors from the request that you sent to your target test application.  The two most likely explanations for the errors you received are:

1. *Your JMeter request is formed correctly, and there is a problem in the target test application that you elicited with your request.*
2. *Your JMeter request to your target test application is malformed, and the response you received is appropriate.*

If the first case is true, then you have managed to uncover a problem with your target test application and therefore have essentially run a positive functional test.

If your situation is better described by the second case, you may want to read more about how to [troubleshoot your JMeter load tests](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2021/09/troubleshoot-your-jmeter-load-tests/).  This is a central task to effective test design and one of the most preeminent challenges facing load test designers.  In other words, the results of your test will only be as sound as the test itself.